# show an image and Responsive in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in a pivture and a text between the picture. 
this is my Pircture : [image]

and I have a text : "HomePage"

 I want to this text("HomePage") place in the middle of the Picture .
and also must be responsive.

Comment: share some code first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="box">
<div class="img"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="text">home page</div>
</div>

.box{position:relative;}

.img{position:relative; z-index:1;}

.text{position:absolute; z-index:2; top:50%; left:0px;}
```

change left according to your requirement